# Simple C function call

Tags: c, function

Trying to call this function in C without any real luck:

```
int sendcommand(char str[256], char reply[256])
```

I have tried many variations such as this:

```
char request[] = "help";
char response[];
int result = sendcommand( request, *response );
```

I've actually done a bit of C and C++ but for some reason I'm missing the boat on something rather basic here.

Comment: That second parm is just wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see that your call is wrong without even knowing what is right...

```
int sendcommand(char str[256], char reply[256])
```

Two formal parameters with the same signature.

```
char request[] = "help";
char response[];
```

Two real parameters with the same type.

So why do you use a different syntax when you pass them?

---

That's not all that is wrong here of course, you need to declare the response parameter with a size sufficient for the return value. Declaring it to the size specified for the formal parameter is safest.

```
char request[] = "help";
char response[256];
int result = sendcommand( request, response );
```

Comment: Great stuff guys.  This brought back some clarity from my old Think C days on the Mac in the 80s.  I had to fix one other minor thing which was to set my project to compile to C++.  Appreciate the help though I do feel a little embarrassed to ask about something so trivial.  C/C++ is just so counter-intuitive after years of Java/C#.

Answer (score 3):

`response` is a pointer, but you're dereferencing it to a `char`, when the function takes a `char*`.

This should work:

```
int result = sendcommand(request, response);
```

Comment: +1, as long as `response` has some space allocated for it.  And `response` isn't a pointer, it's an array.